# Ionic 2 - Make first value in ngFor selected as true

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to display a select list whereby the first value in my ngFor array is selected.

My code is:

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="account" (change)="changeAccount(account)">
  <ion-option *ngFor="#userAccount of userAccountData" value="{{ userAccount.name}}">{{ userAccount.name}}</ion-option>
  <ion-option value="new" checked="false">New Account</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

I would like to know how to place `checked="true"` such that it is only for the first value of the ngFor loop.

Note: I am using a old version of Ionic 2 (`2.0.0-beta.4`) so the syntax is different from current versions which uses `selected="true"`. But would appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `ngModel` instead of `checked="true"`.

In your .js:

```
  this.account = this.userAccountData[0].name;
```

Basically this works the same way as `checked` .